# Coreml's MLModel has memory leakage

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, coreml

Macos Catalina
xcode 11.3

Recently, I encountered a strange memory leakage problem when using MLModel. I put the pseudocode as following.

```
// prediction class
class Prediction {
public:
    Prediction(const std::string &mlmodelc_file);
    ~Prediction();

    void RunPrediction();

private:
    MLPredictionOptions *options_;
    MLModelConfiguration *config_;
    MLModel *mlmodel_;
}

Prediction::Prediction() {
    // set configuration
    options_ = [[MLPredictionOptions alloc] init];
    config_ = [[MLModelConfiguration alloc] init];
    options_.usesCPUOnly = false;
    config_.computeUnits = MLComputeUnitsAll;
    // load mlmodelc file
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *model_path_nsstring = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mlmodelc_file.c_str()];
    NSURL *compiled_model_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:model_path_nsstring isDirectory:YES];
    mlmodel_ = [MLModel modelWithContentsOfURL:compiled_model_url configuration:config_ error:&error];
}

Prediction::~Prediction() {
}

void Prediction::RunPrediction() {
    NSError *error = nil;
    @autoreleasepool {
         [mlmodel_ predictionFromFeatures:model_input options:options_ error:&error];
    }
}
```

```
// There is no memory leakage, if I just create the prediction once, and run the prediction for a loop.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   std::shared_ptr<Prediction> pred = std::make_shared<Prediction>(mlmodelc_file);
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
       pred->RunPrediction();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

```
// But if I put the creation in the loop, memory leakage occurs.
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
       std::shared_ptr<Prediction> pred = std::make_shared<Prediction>(mlmodelc_file);
       pred->RunPrediction();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The MLPredictionOptions, MLModelConfiguration and MLModel are all ARC objects. They should be auto-released after every loop. But it seems that they are not auto-released. I have enable the ARC in xcode. But the memory still increases from 200MB to 2GB and more.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you put the autorelease pool around everything in the loop? (i.e. not in RunPrediction)

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thanks for your reply. It works. And I find that I shoud set  `-fobjc-arc` when building the project .